# Calling smart contract from Javascript

Tags: contract-deployment, javascript, abi

I am newbie at smart contracts and their deploying and I am pretty confused.
I am following this example https://github.com/bellaj/Ballot-Dapp
Someone could explain me well what these lines do, please?

```
var abiArray =[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"proposal","type":"uint256"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proposals","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"voteCount","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"chairperson","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"delegate","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"winningProposal","outputs":[{"name":"winningProposal","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"voter","type":"address"}],"name":"giveRightToVote","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"voters","outputs":[{"name":"weight","type":"uint256"},{"name":"voted","type":"bool"},{"name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"name":"vote","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"proposalNames","type":"bytes32[]"}],"type":"constructor"}]


var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

var contractInstance = MyContract.at('0xd9107d1f3c52bb440256a5f3ad9d6c2c3f38e1ee');// Instantiate from an existing address:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First line**

```
var abiArray =[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"proposal","type":"uint256"}],"name":"vote","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"proposals","outputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"voteCount","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"chairperson","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"to","type":"address"}],"name":"delegate","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"winningProposal","outputs":[{"name":"winningProposal","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"voter","type":"address"}],"name":"giveRightToVote","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"voters","outputs":[{"name":"weight","type":"uint256"},{"name":"voted","type":"bool"},{"name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"name":"vote","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"proposalNames","type":"bytes32[]"}],"type":"constructor"}]
```

**ABI** stands for ***Application Binary Interface*. It describes the smart contract interface representing all attributes and function definitions. So anybody can develop a client and interact with binary contract.

=> Analogy: API

**2nd line**

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);
```

According to the [Web3 documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract):

> Creates a contract object for a solidity contract, which can be used
>   to initiate contracts on an address.

It returns a JavaScript object compatible with the ABI (interface definition).

=> Analogy: API JS Wrapper

**3rd line**

```
var contractInstance = MyContract.at('0xd9107d1f3c52bb440256a5f3ad9d6c2c3f38e1ee');
```

A smart contract can be deployed/instantiated multiple time. The keyword `at` allows you to configure the deployed address for this contract definition.

=> Analogy: API endpoint